# Why is a selection box required in Fabric.js when updating selectable property of objects from false to true?

Tags: reactjs, fabricjs

I have a makeshift image editor that allows users to draw rectangles on an uploaded image. In "draw mode" the rectangles are not selectable, but when I change to move/resize mode (drawMode = false), I'm changing the selectable property of all drawn rectangles to true.

```
const setRectanglesSelectable = () => {
        rectsRef.current.forEach(rect => {
            rect.set({ selectable: !isDrawModeRef.current });
        });

        canvasRef.current?.discardActiveObject().renderAll();
    };

useEffect(() => {
        isDrawModeRef.current = isDrawMode;
        setRectanglesSelectable();
    }, [isDrawMode]);
```

However, when I do this, the rectangles only become selectable if I draw a selection box around them. Once the selection box has been drawn, the selectable property changes correctly when I change the draw mode, and when I switch back to move/resize mode I can now select the rectangles by clicking on them - but only the rectangles that have previously been selected with a selection box. I have no idea why this is happening.

This seems like it should be very straightforward, so I'm not sure what else to try. I've added multiple re-renders, etc. and nothing changes this behavior.